# I use different email accounts in 2 browsers however windows keeps syncing the edge browser to chrome browser)

Tags: email, browser, sync, windows-11

Hey I usually use a different browser for work and home on my home account.
Since moving to windows 11 pro It seems if I use my work email in chrome browser the next time I open /refresh the edge browser it iss logging me out of my home account and synced to my work one.

Does anyone have any idea how to stop this?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Are you days your Edge user profile and Chrome user profile is being synchronized?